# mysql:choosing the most efficient query from the two

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, union

Both of these mysql queries produce exactly the same result but query A is a simple union and it has the where postType clause embedded inside individual queries whereas query B has the same where clause applied to the external select of the virtual table which is a union of individual query results. I am concerned that the virtual table `sigma` from query B might get too large for no good reason if there are a lot of rows but then I am bit confused because how would the order by work for query A ; would it also not have to make a virtual table or something like that for sorting results. All may depend on how order by works for a union ? If order by for a union is also making a temp table ; would then query A almost equate to query B in resources(it will be much easier for us to implement query B in our system compared to query A)? Please guide/advise in any way possible, thanks

Query A

> ```
> SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.*
>             FROM `t1` INNER JOIN `t2` ON
>             `t1`.websiteID= `t2`.ownerID
>             AND `t1`.authorID= `t2`.authorID
>             AND `t1`.authorID=1559 AND `t1`.postType="simplePost"
> UNION
>             SELECT `t1`.*
>              FROM `t1` where websiteID=1559 AND postType="simplePost" 
> ORDER BY postID limit 0,50
> ```

Query B

> ```
> Select * from (
> SELECT `t1`.*,`t2`.*
>             FROM `t1` INNER JOIN `t2` ON
>              `t1`.websiteID= `t2`.ownerID
>               AND `t1`.authorID= `t2`.authorID
>             AND `t1`.authorID=1559
> UNION
>             SELECT `t1`.*
>              FROM `t1` where websiteID=1559
> )
> As sigma  where postType="simplePost" ORDER BY postID limit 0,50
> ```

EXPLAIN FOR QUERY A

> ```
> id    type                table           type    possible_keys   keys            key_len ref         rows    Extra
> 1     PRIMARY             t2              ref     userID          userID          4       const       1       
> 1     PRIMARY             t1              ref     authorID        authorID        4       const       2       Usingwhere
> 2     UNION               t1              ref     websiteID       websiteID       4       const       9       Usingwhere
> NULL  UNIONRESULT         <union1,2>      ALL     NULL            NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    Usingfilesort
> ```

EXPLAIN FOR QUERY B

> ```
> id    select_type     table       type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
> 1     PRIMARY         <derived2>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL    10      Using where; Using filesort
> 2     DERIVED         t2          ref     userID          userID          4               1   
> 2     DERIVED         t1          ref     authorID        authorID        4               2       Using where
> 3     UNION           t1          ref     websiteID       websiteID       4               9   
> NULL  UNION RESULT    <union2,3>  ALL     NULL            NULL        NULL        NULL    NULL
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to have the same row returned from both queries? If so, do you require duplicates to be eliminated?

Comment: I understand you are pointing towards speedy union all and no, the query does not return duplicates.

The main concern is regarding the impact of the following's use


1) result_from_union_of_two_selects ORDER BY something 
versus 
2) SELECT * FROM (result_from_union_of_two_selects) AS sigma ORDER BY something

Comment: Please don't cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73825/efficient-query-involving-union-and-virtual-derived-table One question, in one site, is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no doubt that version 1 - separate where clauses in each side of the union - will be faster. Let's look at why version - where clause over the union result - is worse:

- data volume: there's always going to be more rows in the union result, because there are less conditions on what rows are returned. This means more disk I/O (depending on indexes), more temporary storage to hold the rowset, which means more processing time
- repeated scan: the entire result of the union must be scanned again to apply the condition, when it could have been handled during the initial scan. This means double handling the rowset, albeit probably in-memory, still it's extra work.
- indexes aren't used for where clauses on a union result. If you have an index over the foreign key fields *and* postType, it would not be used

If you want maximum performance, use `UNION ALL`, which passes the rows straight out into the result with no overhead, instead of `UNION`, which removes duplicates (usually by sorting) and can be expensive and is unnecessary based in your comments

Define these indexes and use version 1 for maximum performance:

```
create index t1_authorID_postType on t1(authorID, postType);
create index t1_websiteID_postType on t1(websiteID, postType);
```

Comment: correct approach, logically sound & we already have indexes on the fields .thanks

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this would work in lieu:

```
SELECT
     `t1`.*
    ,`t2`.*
FROM `t1`
LEFT JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.websiteID = `t2`.ownerID
    AND `t1`.authorID = `t2`.authorID
    AND `t1`.authorID = 1559
WHERE ( `t1`.authorID = 1559 OR `t1`.websiteID = 1559 )
    AND `t1`.postType = 'simplePost'
ORDER BY postID limit 0 ,50
```

Comment: I have already tried this. I was initially glad that I didnt have to use Unions but when I used EXPLAIN to see what was happening I saw mysql was utilizing a union in the background which pretty much cancels the whole benefit of using this query. So, I realized that the most minimum of logic for this query to work requires a union, no matter what.